# Constructor is not working, doesn't accept arguments later when called?

Tags: java, methods, constructor, stringbuffer

So for an assignment I'm doing (still beginner) I have a default constructor for a class called Anagram and it looks like this:

```
private StringBuffer word1, word2

public void Anagram(String s, String d){

    StringBuffer word1 = new StringBuffer(s);
    StringBuffer word2 = new StringBuffer(d);
}
```

But when I call this method from another file,like so:

```
public Opponent(){
    Anagram an = new Anagram(RandomWord.nextWord(),RandomWord.nextWord());
    turn = 0;
}
```

I get an error saying the constructor does not accept any arguments? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`public void Anagram(String s, String d){` is not a constructor ,constructors don't have return types change it to `public Anagram(String s, String d){`

Answer (score 0):

`Anagram` is considered a regular method in this case because constructor has its own special syntax

```
public Anagram(String s1, String s2) {}
```

so it doesn't declare what type it returns.